# Makefile - how to fix libc dependency?

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I want to statically link Tk into my code. I am running into trouble due to dependencies. The modification I made to my Makefile is:

```
TK_LIBS_64 = \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 \
    -lX11 \
    -lXss \
    -lXext \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 \
    -lXft \
    -lX11 \
    -lfontconfig \
    -lfreetype \
    -lxmlparse \
    -lexpat \
    -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 \
    -lXrender  \
    -lpthread \
    -ldl \
    -lpthread \
    -lieee \
    -lm

LIBS64 = \
    -L$(TCL_ROOT)/lib/ -ltk8.5 \
    $(TK_LIBS_64)
```

I get the following error on compilation:

```
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x7f): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal':
: undefined reference to `__libc_setup_tls'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x86): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal':
: undefined reference to `_dl_cpuclock_offset'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0xc0): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal':
: undefined reference to `_errno'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0xcb): In function `__pthread_initialize_minimal':
: undefined reference to `_h_errno'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x289): In function `pthread_initialize':
: undefined reference to `_res'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x3cc): In function `pthread_initialize':
: undefined reference to `_dl_init_static_tls'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x947): In function `__pthread_reset_main_thread':
: undefined reference to `_errno'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x955): In function `__pthread_reset_main_thread':
: undefined reference to `_h_errno'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(pthread.o)(.text+0x963): In function `__pthread_reset_main_thread':
: undefined reference to `_res'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(ptw-write.o)(.text+0x1a): In function `write':
: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(ptw-write.o)(.text+0x72): In function `write':
: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(ptw-read.o)(.text+0x1a): In function `read':
: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(ptw-read.o)(.text+0x72): In function `read':
: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(ptw-close.o)(.text+0x1a): In function `close':
: undefined reference to `__syscall_error'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libpthread.a(ptw-close.o)(.text+0x5e): more undefined references to `__syscall_error' follow
/usr/lib/../lib64/libdl.a(dlopen.o)(.text+0x5): In function `dlopen':
: undefined reference to `__dlopen'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libdl.a(dlsym.o)(.text+0x5): In function `dlsym':
: undefined reference to `__dlsym'
/usr/lib/../lib64/libdl.a(dlerror.o)(.text+0x1): In function `dlerror':
: undefined reference to `__dlerror'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
dmake: Fatal error: Command failed for target
```

The undefined references are either in libc.a or libc_p.a and adding them to the dependencies does not help. Since the undefined references are system calls I think I am missing something basic here. I would be obliged if someone can point out the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use -pthread instead of -lpthread